# How to show Xbutton(clear button) always visible in uisearchbar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, uibutton, ios5.1

In my application, I am adding a [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar).

My intent is to enable the UISearch Bar "X button"(clear button in [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield)) to be always visible.

I have tried using the following code below to try to make the "X Button" be always visible. However, it does not work. If I set `tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever`, the clear button in [uitextfield](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) not showing. I am not sure what is wrong?

I would really appreciate anyone's help here. Why is this not working?

#### Code (Not working)

```
for (UIView* v in searchBar.subviews)
{
    if ( [v isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]] )
    {
        UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)v;
        tf.delegate = self;
        tf.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        break;
    }
}
```

#### Goal:

I want to always show the clear button if the text length is equal to 0

- i.e. if I don't input any text.

Comment: check Shows Cancel Button in your .xib

Comment: what i meant is i don't want "Cancel" -- text button. My requirement is always visible "X "mark button in uisearch bar. that means uitextfield that is in uisearchbar, clear button (uitextfield clear button "x") always need to visible

Comment: @banu, It the default behavior of the search bar.

Comment: can i customize this?

Comment: I think No because if the textfield is blank then no need to press it.

Comment: my requirement is always show. if textfield is blank then if user click clearbutton, textfield should resign from first responder.

Comment: for resign from textfield, use the cancel button.

Comment: i am doing custom clear button. so if it is not possible, sure i will accept your answer.

Comment: @Rushabh i am working on custom clear button as you suggest, if its working correctly sure i will accept.

Answer (score 4):

```
UITextField *searchBarTextField = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subview;
            searchBarTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi iPatel i am also adding same code. but X button disappear when the text is blank.

Comment: @iPatel - Sir what are you telling new ?

Comment: @banu- put this code in viewDidLoad *(after create you UISearchBar)* method

Comment: @iPatel - Just have a look at the question not just the title of question.

Comment: @TheTiger- sir ji.. if you have doubt then explain me where i m wrong. put this code at  viewDidLoad (after create you UISearchBar)

Comment: @iPatel bhanu has already mentioned in his question what are you telling. And BTW try it yourself it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior of the search bar. Because if the `UITextField` is blank then there is no need to press it.

Comment: Hi user2526811. i know but my requirement is if text will be blank then if user click the clear button textfield should resign first responder.

Answer (score 1):

U can do it in Xib. I am attaching the screenshot.

[image]

And programmatically

```
myUITextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: ya i set manually in coding, because i am using UISearchbar. @user2526811 says this is default behavior. can i create custom clear button for UITextField..?

Comment: She is asking for the searchBar Not TextField.

Comment: yes if there is nothing in the search bar then it did not show. try to add some character. it is default behaviour

Comment: People on this question are having an extremely difficult time with the concept of always.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get it but unfortunately , **There is no Way of Customising with the ClearButton(X) of UITextField .**

There is a way that If You only need it to get resign the KeyBoard , Then just overriding this method :

> Just clear the field yourself and call  resignFirstResponder .

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.text = @"";
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}
```

Documentation about it [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear%3a)

Comment: no its costume clear button working fine. i will post complete code

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but I came here with an equal customer request: "Show the clearButton as soon as the cursor is in the searchField. We want to be able to cancel the search with this button in any stage". 
I came up with a solution other than adding a custom button:

AppleDocs:

> UITextFieldViewModeAlways The overlay view is always displayed if the
>   text field contains text.

So adding a whitespace as the first character will set the clearButton active.
The leading whitespace can be removed as soon as text is entered in the searchField or at any other point before using the text.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //adding a whitespace at first start sets the clearButton active
    textField.text = @" ";
}


-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    ...
    NSString *completeNewString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    //remove the dummyWhitespace (here or later in code, as needed)
    self.searchString = [completeNewString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    ...
    return YES;
}
```