# UITextField clear button color Swift

Tags: swift, button, uitextfield, background-color

How can I change clear button color or background color in UITextField. I tried  get subviews of textField, but in subviews not clear button.

Comment: refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944781/how-to-change-the-tint-color-of-the-clear-button-on-a-uitextfield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for view in subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton {
                button.setImage(button.image(for: .normal)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
                button.tintColor = .white
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Can you say how can I change content color of button? I want change cross color. Now cross color is text field background color.

Comment: Great trick! Perhaps a more appropriate hook would be in `didAddSubview(_:)` to ensure the clear button is re-configured only once when added to the view hierarchy.